# ld: undefined symbol vs ld: undefined reference

Tags: gnu, ld, undefined-reference, binutils, undefined-symbol

What is the difference between these errors in GNU Binutils ld ?

- undefined reference
- undefined symbol

I have a good understanding of undefined reference: This occurs for example when the loader cannot find the implementation of a function.  I am curious to know the cause of undefined symbol.

Comment: I also have similar question, for this testing program:

int func();
int main(){
    func();
}

It gets `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64` on mac m1 but `undefined reference to func()` on linux

Answer (score 3):

e.g. when you do some arithmetic in your linkerscript using a symbol which is not yet defined. In my situation, this is mostly due to typo's.

```
_syma = 1 ;
_syna += 1 ;
/* error: undefined symbol `_syna' referenced in expression */
```

or

```
_syma = 1 ;
_symb = _syna + 1 ;
/* error: undefined symbol `_syna' referenced in expression */
```

When you assign an output section to an undefined symbol, you get another error:

```
_syma = 1 ;
.text _syna :
/* error: non constant or forward reference address expression for section .text */
{
  *(.text) ;
}
```