# Undefined symbol vs undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference, undefined-symbol

I saw this post here: [ld: undefined symbol vs ld: undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789428/ld-undefined-symbol-vs-ld-undefined-reference) and I don't think it really talks about what the differences are between these 2 linker errors.

I usually get `undefined reference` linker errors when the linker can't find the definition of something (or I declared it and forgot to define it), but it seems `undefined symbol` serves the same purpose (the answer in the above linked post gives an example that seems to be aligned with when `undefined reference` arises, but maybe I'm missing some subtlety here?), so I'm a bit confused. Can someone clarify, perhaps with examples, of when each one arises during linking?

Edit: I didn't know the terminology for linker errors could be dependent on if using `gnu`, `clang`, etc...

In my case, I saw the `undefined symbol` error when using `clang++` and the error was

```
stderr: ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: custom::linear::adapt()
```

Is `undefined symbol` the `clang` counterpart to `gnu`'s `undefined reference`?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking about "undefined reference" (as emitted by the GNU ld linker in e.g. Linux) versus "unresolved external symbol" (as emitted by the MSVC linker in Windows)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh I had thought these linker error terminology were uniform across different linkers. I just checked my codebase and it runs a continuous integration test with clang++ `clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` and the error was `stderr: ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: custom::linear::adapt()`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) might be a duplicate. The first answer shows GCC and MSVC output for the same code, one says reference, the other says symbol. I imagine clang also just uses "symbol"

Comment: @ChrisMM Is there a difference between `undefined symbol` and `unresolved external symbol`?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. Some compilers call it one or the other depending on the linker used.